# Regular expression for Digits, Decimal, Hyphen and Brackets at any position

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I want a regular expression to allow following characters, at any position:

Number 0-9, Space, Decimal, +, ., (, )

By any position i mean, eg: Decimal can come before digits or after digits.

I can allow 0 to max 16 characters.

TIA.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are saying that `.` and `))))` are valid strings? All the answers so far follow this interpretation (because that's what you said) but I'm guessing you have additional constraints which you haven't communicated.

Comment: Yes, they are valid strings. I am supposed to allow none others charaters except these.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just create a character class with the characters you need

```
[0-9 ,+.()]
```

Then add the quantifier

```
[0-9 ,+.()]{0,16}
```

and at last, put anchors around it

```
^[0-9 ,+.()]{0,16}$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 ValidationExpression="^([0-9a-zA-Z-_'.,/ ]*)$"
```

Add your allowed content within `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this regex.

```
^([\d \.(),+]{0,16})$
```